# Having some issue with post/get request using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, slim

I am passing some data over to a route when a specific option is selected from the form. I test the value and its coming over but when i try to use a if statement is doesn't work see code below:

```
$app->post('/fdfd', function ($request, $response) {


$params = $request->getParams();
  $val =  $params['file']; //value coming over is = "pipe"
  $users = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `stock`")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  foreach ($users as $cat) {
    if ($cat->category == $val) {
      $name = $cat->name;
      echo "<option value='test'>$name</option>";
    } else {
      echo "False";
    }
  }
})->setName('lazyy');
```

I am sure the value is coming over because if i change the if statement to == "pipe and print $val it shows pipe.

Is it that the value is taking long to come over from the form and the code is being run without it? Ive been trying to figure it out any help would be appreciated.

But if i change the value of $val explicitly to pipe it works. The code below works when i change $val to pipe.

```
$app->post('/fdfd', function ($request, $response) {
  $params = $request->getParams();
  $val =  "pipe";
  $users = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `stock`")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  sleep(2);
  foreach ($users as $cat) {
    if ($cat->category == $val) {
      $name = $cat->name;
      echo "<option value='test'>$val</option>";
    } else {
      echo "False";
    }
  }
})->setName('lazyy');
```

See jQuery code below if needed:

```
$("#catId").on("change", function() {
          var category = document.getElementById("catId").value
          $.post("{{ path_for('lazyy') }}", {
            file:category
          }, function(data) {
            $("#dift").html(data);
          });
        })
```

Comment: `"..value is taking long to come.."` = No. Check what is actually sent. Don't understand why you don't use `where` in your db query

Comment: I checked what is sent and its getting the value and they are both strings. So don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Tried using the where for the database but same result